# How to add metadata to a token whose mint is a PDA?

Tags: metaplex, pda, token, metadata, cpi

My token is program-controlled, i.e. my mint address (and authority) is a PDA.

For that reason, I have to create code within my Solana Program to add metadata to my token.

While I can easily mint, it has been a weekslong painful endeavor to try to cut through the jungle of metaplex complexities to achieve a simple feat: Add metadata to my token. So that it appears nicely in my customers' Phantom wallets.

I've created a github repo with the essence of the code I'm trying to get to work, see [github addMeta](https://github.com/bernieblume/addMeta).

Here's the error message I'm stuck at:

```
  1) addmeta
       Sets the token metadata:
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7891:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:7848:20)
      at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:172:23)
      at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/provider.js:88:20)
      at async MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/rpc.js:15:24)
      at async Context.<anonymous> (tests/addmeta.js:58:5)
```

See code on [github addMeta](https://github.com/bernieblume/addMeta).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing an account. Briefly scanning through your code seems you are missing the metaplex token metadata program. You just call `mpl_token_metadata::id()`, but you need to add it to your context.

Comment: @Omega, your comment should probably be an answer instead!

Comment: Agreed. It should be an answer. @ome

Comment: Tried passing metadata_program_id as an 8th account to the context, even though only 7 accounts are documented. At what position should I pass the 8th account? I tried first, last and a few others, but keep getting either "The program expected this account to be already initialized" (for `mint`) or "instruction expected an executable account" (for unspecified account). Are there any examples out there on how to call create_metadata_accounts_v3 properly, or at least some documentation that's accurate and includes all necessary accounts?

Comment: OK I'm one step further. I figured I accidentally tested on localnet, and it is clear we don't have a working metadata program there, so the error "expected and executable account" makes sense. Tried on Devnet, but getting `custom program error: 0xb` there. What is custom error 0xb and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is working now  Added the token_metadata_program_id and had to debug some metaplex error codes (name too long). Thanks Omega!

Comment: Ok great I created an answer for this. Glad it solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an account. Briefly scanning through your code seems you are missing the metaplex token metadata program.

You just call `mpl_token_metadata::id()`, but you need to add it to your context.